# Use 'expect' in Bash with responses in any order

Tags: linux, bash, input, terminal, expect

I'm using this expect file (keygen.exp) to generate SSH key, I'm using ssh-keygen just as example to test 'expect':

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-keygen

expect "Enter file"
send "./id_rsa\r"

expect "Enter passphrase"
send "\r"

expect "Enter same passphrase"
send "\r"

interact
```

It works perfectly, however, **what if the order of the prompts for inputs is not the same every run, and there might be different questions on different runs**?

I want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh-keygen

expect if-is "Enter file"
send "./id_rsa\r"

expect if-is "Enter passphrase"
send "\r"

expect if-is "Enter same passphrase"
send "\r"

interact
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason why not to do `ssh-keygen -f ./id_rsa -P ''`?

Comment: im using ssh-keygen just as example for using 'expect'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have single expect statement which loops, processing different outputs differently, something like:

```
expect {
  "Enter file" {
    send "./id_rsa\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  "Enter passphrase" {
    send "\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  "Enter same passphrase" {
    send "\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  $ 
}
```

But note that you need some way to break out of the loop.  The last pattern here - `$` has no `exp_continue` (or any other action) so it will break out of the loop **if** the prompt you get when logged in includes `$`.
See the full documentation at https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html

Comment: i replaced by 3 expect lines with your expect block, but it didn't work. Could you add the full expect file content?

Comment: thanks, Colin. I removed the '$' line, removed the 'interact' line, and it worked!

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that worked.  If you have no explicit matching for a prompt to break out of the loop it will break out when no matching input is received within a timeout - 10 seconds by default.

Answer (score 0):

Expect in any order, with infinite timeout:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /path/to/some-programme

expect {
  "some string" {
    set timeout -1
    send "some input\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  "some other string" {
    set timeout -1
    send "some other input\r"
    exp_continue
  }
  ...
}

#no 'interact'
#end of file
```